# How do I split String after every word and print second string to next line?

Tags: android

I'm trying to split a String after every word, so that I print a word in one line and the remainder of the string in the next line.

This is my code,

```
// this method returns String seperated by new line after each word
public String getA(String p){

    System.out.println("@@ sectin name : "+p);
    se.clear();
    String [] tokens = p.split("[\\s']");
    String e = "";
    for(String s:tokens){
        System.out.println("@@ for --> ");
        System.out.println("@@ split s "+s);
        e=s+"\n";
        System.out.println("@@ split e "+e);          
    }    
    System.out.println("@@ for --> return ");
    return (e);
}
```

but I'm not getting what I want. How could I improve ?

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: What you want if this method returns String seperated by new line after each word? replaceText = replaceText.replace(' ', '\n');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do `e += s + "\n";` instead of `e = s + "\n";`.

Try this,

```
for (String s : tokens) {
    e += s + "\n"; // Shorthand for e = e + s + "\n";
}
```

But as @Zaki Pathan suggested, you could use the `replaceAll` method instead.

```
String p = "This is a sentance";
p = p.replaceAll("[\\s']", "\n");
```

Comment: but i have a string  "General Stores" . Im getting this String  from json.

Comment: im unable to split this and set it to textView.

Comment: Sorry. It was my fault.